# Processing xsd with xsl without namespaces

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, schema

I have a problem with processing xsd using xsl. My xsd file begins:

```
<schema targetNamespace="http://www.bleble.com"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<complexType name="blabla">
...
```

so there's no namespace to recognize tags by xsl.

I can't modify xsd files, because there's a lot of code and a lot of files, so only possible way is to create a suitable xsl transformation file.

I've been trying to add namespace:

```
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

without adding it to tags:

```
<complexType name="blabla">
```

but it it's not valid with xml standard.

Thanks for help!

Comment: You need to be clearer about what you've tried. Do you mean you added the xmlns:xsd namespace prefix declaration *to your XSL stylesheet*? What do you mean by "without adding it to tags" ... without using the namespace prefix in your XPath expressions? What do you mean by "it's not valid" - please show the code that you think is invalid (in more context), and tell what makes you think it's not valid. The namespace prefix declaration you showed is certainly well-formed, and doesn't make an XSL stylesheet "not valid".

Comment: Also, questions and answers on this topic will be much easier to understand if you distinguish between "namespace" and "namespace prefix" and "namespace prefix declaration", instead of calling them all "namespace". E.g. when you say "there's no namespace", that's just not true. Evidently you mean "there's no namespace prefix". It may be that you're not familiar with how namespace declarations work. I don't fault you for that, but would offer the advice that this is an area where an hour of dedicated study of the basics will make life vastly easier and avoid hours of frustration later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confused!

You say: "so there's no namespace to recognize tags by xsl". But there is a namespace - the namespace is http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema. There's no prefix, but prefixes don't matter to XSLT; the only thing you need to know in order to write XSLT processing code is the namespace URI. For example, if you want to match a complexType element you will need to write the equivalent of

```
<xsl:template match="ajkt:complexType" xmlns:ajkt="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
```

Of course, you will normally use a prefix that is more recognizable than ajkt (perhaps xs or xsd), and you will normally put the declaration on the xsl:stylesheet element, but that's just cosmetic.

Comment: Yep! I've got it! Thank's so much!

Answer (score 3):

**This is the most FAQ both in XPath and in XSLT** -- search for "default namespace in XPath" and you will find many good explanations.

The quick answer is that to select an element with unprefixed name that is in a default namespace (whose namespace-uri isn't the empty string), you need in the XSLT code to bind a prefix to the namespace and to reference any unprefixed element name with the prefix so defined.

**In this particular case**:

```
//complexType
```

selects nothing, because the XPath processor is looking for an element named `complexType` that is in "no namespace", but all elements in the document are in the `"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"` namespace.

You already have bound the prefix `xsd` to the default namespace of the source XML document -- then use:

```
//xsd:complexType
```